# How to speed up a video in the VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I'm making a tutorial, after a little work of strip I would like to speed up the video the seconds seems last longer (maybe because I've use video of different qualities) so I would like to increase the velocity at which the video is played even at a velocity greater than the original one.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do this by adding a **Speed Control** effect strip to the selected strip.

[image]

There are two methods for controlling the speed:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Another +1 Thanks for the help today! but how can apply it to the whole project seems I can't use it in more then 3 scene together...

Comment: You are welcome. Remember the trick in my last answer? Ctrl G to make them as a meta strip. Meta strip can be treated like normal strip, too. :)

Comment: This is so confusing, so much that I opened a bug  https://developer.blender.org/T71800