# Video footage becomes slower than the 3d after animation render

Tags: rendering, video

So, I'm trying to composite my 3d character with my video. My video was 1920x1080p with 23.97fps. So I set the render setting on blender to 1920x1080p and 23.97fps. But when I do render, after it finished, my video play slower than my 3d. It's like my video becomes a slow motion video. How did I get this? Any help would be appreciated.

---

I play on Movies&TV app on Win10
I render it under AVI JPEG format on blender

Comment: How are you playing said video? From where? With which software? Under what video or image format? With what settings

Comment: If you are using a different frame rate for the scene and the video footage, you can certainly expect your footage not to play back correctly. You would need to transcode the footage to the scene's framerate or use a [speed control strip](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7182/1853) on the VSE