# Two Framerates at Once - Render 24 and 12 FPS at the same time

Tags: rendering, animation, frame-rate

I'd like the camera to move at 24 FPS but have everything moving at 12 FPS.

Is there a way I can do this in Blender?

I'm rendering using Eevee.

Thank you.

Comment: Since the FPS is mostly a playback speed, you just have to set 12 fps and make the camera move twice as fast or set 24 fps and make everything else move half as fast...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put everything you want to appear at 12fps in *NLA Strips* and add *Stepped Interpolation* modifiers:

[image: Animation]
[image: Still]
Hope this helps! Peace and God bless!

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! Don't think I ever even noticed that the NLA also had modifiers.

Answer (score 1):

So, if what you essentially want is *2x fast motion*, then just change the *Time Remapping* option's NEW from 100 to 50 which is located in Output Properties > Dimensions.

But, by 12 FPS, if you want the same frame to get repeated two times, then first render out the animation into a image sequence and then see [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7181/how-to-speed-up-a-video-in-the-vse)